# how to make default null in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

```
create table patient (
    p_code number(5) primary key,
    p_name varchar2(50) not null,
    DOB date(15) not null,
    p_phone number(30)   default null,
    st varchar2(20) not null,
    city varchar2(15) not null,
    state varchar2(15)   default null,
    zip_code number(10) not null,
    w_code number(5) references ward (w_code)  
)
```

it gives me `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: by default its null, you don't need to say default null.

Answer (score 1):

In all databases, the default value for a column is `NULL` when you leave out `not null`.  So, you can write:

```
create table patient (
    p_code number(5) not null primary key,
    p_name varchar2(50) not null,
    DOB date not null,
    p_phone number(30),
    st varchar2(20) not null,
    city varchar2(15) not null,
    state varchar2(15),
    zip_code number(10) not null,
    w_code number(5) references ward (w_code)  
)
```

As a note.  Oracle also accepts `null` and `default null` for this purpose, so these are also acceptable:

```
    p_phone number(30) null,
    p_phone number(30) default null,
```

The problem with your code was the `date(15)`.  `date` doesn't take a length argument.

By the way, you should be storing phone numbers and zip codes using strings and not numbers.  They can have leading zeros.